# Add taxonomy term image to a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Can anybody tell me how I add an image field of a taxonomy term to a view of nodes with reference to the vocabolary?

I have a content type called "Product" and one called "Distributors". And then a have a vocabolary called "Product categories", where a term has two fields: a title field and an image field.

I am using the [NAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/nat) module to add a term to the "Product categories" vocabulary every time a product is created, so that the title and image of the product becomes a new term with the value of these two fields.

When I create a distributor I am using these terms as term reference to which products the distributor sells.

The problem I am facing now is that I want a view of distributors, and I cant seem to get the image of the terms associated with each distributor-node. I can only get the titles. I assume that I might have to make some kind of relasionship, but I cant seem to figure it out.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you have a distributor node that has a term reference (multi value) to Product categories.

In your view that lists the distributors you must add a relationship: Content: Taxonomy terms on node. When presented with a choice of vocabularies you select 'Product Category'.

[image]

Then you add two fields: Taxonomy term: Name, and Taxonomy term: Image (your image field might be named slightly differently). For both of these fields, during the multi form process of adding them, you will be presented with a form that says for instance: Configure field: Taxonomy term: Name. Here you must select the Relationship as term.

[image]

This will create one row for each taxonomy term on the node, which might not be what you want. You can now group it under the content:title of the distributor.

[image]

There are two other ways that I can see by which you can group all of the images from one distributor under a single distributor.

**First method:**

Create a new field: global custom text. Make sure that it is below all of the distributor fields. Move the image field below it. In this global text field add all of the distributor fields (using html and replacement patterns) except for the image field. For instance, you might have something like this:

```
<div>[title]</div>
<div>[address]</div>
<div>[phone]</div>
```

Now go and hide all of the fields, the global text field as well, except for the image field. Then in your grouping, select this new global text field as the field to group on. Now apply some CSS to make it look good. And if you want to get rid of that pesky h3 tag around the grouping header, then override the theme view template. Click on Theme: Information in views and select one of the Style output templates.

**Second method:**

Install the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. This allows you to create a field in a view that will be the result of another view.

Create a new view that takes as contextual filter the nid of the distributor, and then as before add a relationship to the terms etc. so that this view only outputs the pictures in groups.

In your original view remove the relationship to the terms, and insert a field to the new view, and make sure to pass it the parameter of the nid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im getting closer, but it is still not exactly what i wanted. I have made a wireframe of what i have now and what i want. I still get two rows with the grouping, but i only want one row displaying all of the terms images together:
http://tinypic.com/r/f2ltv6/8

Comment: Updated my answer and gave you two options to choose from. First option is preferable but requires a little CSS magic.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but could not make it work. It only prints the image for the first term. Not the second image. 
Man, I thought there was a pretty straight forward solution to this problem..

Comment: Tell you what. Install [bundle copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy), export you type definitions for your distributor node type and product category vocabulary (and any dependencies), and export your view and post it somewhere and I will assists if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I have put it in three txt files, and zip'ed it here:
http://mortenneessen.dk/dist/distributors.zip

Comment: [download link for files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCGrZF4E6Y2ajJaNGowZzByM00/edit?usp=sharing) This works. but you will have to apply CSS and change the global text field's output to your liking. There was no term reference field on the distributor (which was your problem), so I took out the product image and replaced with the term reference field. You must re-import the distributor bundle and view. I also include the views template file that you can drop into your theme template folder. You can change the h3 tag to something more to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) I dont understand why there are no term refenrence on the distributor - there has been one.. But maybe i accidently deleted it while trying different approaches. I will have a look at your files later today, and thank you again for your help :)