# How to display block with term image field when viewing term node

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using the default Taxonomy term view in drupal 7.
I have Vocabulary: Portfolio with terms: Wedding Photos, Kids Photos, Other Photos. And I want to show a block of the term image field when a specific term is visited.

similar to this ( [Add taxonomy term image to a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126496/add-taxonomy-term-image-to-a-view) )

But because there are many content types in the same category the block is showing many term image fields instead of just one.
I try different Contextual filters and Relationships and Query settings: Distinct. But no result so far.

Comment: Did you set a filter?

Comment: No.Which filter

Comment: If you wanted the wedding photo to show then you'd filter on the term id (Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)) for wedding so as to exclude any other images; also set the limit to 1 result in case there are many wedding term images.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error: In the Format: Settings I had Grouping field N1 selected with the category term image field, which caused the duplication of the image.

**Contextual Filters**: Content has taxonomy term ID (with depth), Depth:0, Provide Default Value: Taxonomy term ID from URL > Load default filter from term page
**Relationships**: Entity Reference: VocabularyName - Require this relationship
**Fields**: Taxonomy Term - the term image field - using [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) I select Filter Repeats